# Identificar o tipo de variável recebida em uma função genérica

Tags: delphi, funções, variáveis, genéricos

Tenho uma função em Delphi que recebe um tipo de dados genérico, gostaria de saber qual o tipo de dado recebido, tipo assim:

```
function MinhaFuncao<T>(): T
```

Preciso saber qual o tipo que esta em `<T>`.

Comment: ainda não, (eu ja consegui usando RTTI), tenho um form generico de consulta: quando eu o instancio eu passo um tipo <T> para ele, é esse <T> que me diz qual a classe que ele tem que mainupular nesta consulta e quando o usuario seleciona um item na grid eu tenho que retornar uma instancia desta classe populada, exemplo passo pra ele um TPessoa e quando o usuario selecionar ele tem que me retornar uma Pessoa

Answer (score 1):

Para saber o tipo de variável que temos na função pode se usar a seguinte procedimento, exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.ShowBasicVariantType(varVar: Variant);
var typeString: string;
   basicType : Integer;
begin
  basicType := VarType(varVar) and VarTypeMask;

  case basicType of
    varEmpty     : typeString := 'varEmpty';
    varNull      : typeString := 'varNull';
    varSmallInt  : typeString := 'varSmallInt';
    varInteger   : typeString := 'varInteger';
    varSingle    : typeString := 'varSingle';
    varDouble    : typeString := 'varDouble';
    varCurrency  : typeString := 'varCurrency';
    varDate      : typeString := 'varDate';
    varOleStr    : typeString := 'varOleStr';
    varDispatch  : typeString := 'varDispatch';
    varError     : typeString := 'varError';
    varBoolean   : typeString := 'varBoolean';
    varVariant   : typeString := 'varVariant';
    varUnknown   : typeString := 'varUnknown';
    varByte      : typeString := 'varByte';
    varWord      : typeString := 'varWord';
    varLongWord  : typeString := 'varLongWord';
    varInt64     : typeString := 'varInt64';
    varStrArg    : typeString := 'varStrArg';
    varString    : typeString := 'varString';
    varAny       : typeString := 'varAny';
    varTypeMask  : typeString := 'varTypeMask';
  end;

  ShowMessage('Variant type is '+typeString);
end;
```

Código para chamar a função:

```
var myVar : Variant;
begin
  ShowMessage('Variant value = not yet set');
  ShowBasicVariantType(myVar);

  myVar := 123;
  ShowMessage('Variant value = 123');
  ShowBasicVariantType(myVar);

  myVar := myVar + 456;
  ShowMessage('Variant value = 123 + 456');
  ShowBasicVariantType(myVar);

  myVar := 'String '+IntToStr(myVar);
  ShowMessage('Variant value = String 579');
  ShowBasicVariantType(myVar);
end;
```

Result:

> Variant value = not yet set
>   Variant type  = varEmpty
>   Variant value = 123
>   Variant type  = varByte
>   Variant value = 123 + 456
>   Variant type  = varInt64
>   Variant value = String 579
>   Variant type  = varString

Para mais informações consulte o [DelphiBasics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=VarType), pode ainda ver [aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/como-descobrir-o-tipo-de-uma-variavel/252315) tem mais um exemplo possível.

Comment: Obrigado, pelo retorno! Eu não sei se consegui explicar, mais é assim: MinhaFuncao<T> : T

Comment: @LucianoFerreira só precisa de mudar a procedure para function e na primeira linha da sua MinhaFuncao a função

Comment: MinhaFuncao<T>(): T    pode ser um TPessoa, TProduto, TMarca, essa tratativa tambem serve para identificar esses tipos de classes, atualmente estou usando RTTI,

Comment: tipo assim: "if T is TPessoa then ..."